# Jmeter: How to customize/scripted in Jmeter to handle leave approvals scenario

Tags: jmeter

Pleas guide how can below scenario be customized/scripted in Jmeter for load testing.

Scenario: Approve leaves

1. Login as Manager> Go to leaves list (would display all the requested leaves for approval)> Select all and click Approve

I am able to extract the dynamic values from responses however not able to understand how can i be able to dynamically handle leave requests.

Leaves list request: shows all requests's employee codes with other data (like code, leave from and to, reason and all)

I am using CSV file to login with different manager ids. However since each manager will have different number of leave requests (recorded the script with one manager login who has 8 requests) and if i run with different manager ids, how to handle different leave requests with different employee codes.

Subsequent requests have below kind of POST data which can be extracted from leaves list request:

```
{ Code:'12345', name: 'xxx', iLeaveId:2345,Type:9, stype: 'Casual',  dNoofDays: 3, sFromdate: '01 Aug 2013', sTodate: '04 Aug 2013', sFromopt: 'Full Day', sToopt: 'Full Day', Reason: 'test',}
```

Please pardon if the question is not clear/framing is not communicative.

Comment: add example of response which need to get dynamic value and example of request using the dynamic value

Comment: Thanks for reply. The response is as below (code and names, dates will change based on the logged in manager){"d":["[{\"RowNo\":676,\"EMPCODE\":\"1234\",\"EMP_CODE\":\"ABC123\",\"EMPNAME\":\"test123\",\"DATE\":\"05 Jun 2017\",\"WORKDATE\":\"05 Jun 2017\","RowNo\":676,\"EMPCODE\":\"5678\",\"EMP_CODE\":\"ABC1234\",\"EMPNAME\":\"test1234\",\"DATE\":\"05 Jun 2017\",\"WORKDATE\":\"05 Jun 2017\"...}

Comment: And the request: { Code:'12345', name: 'xxx', iLeaveId:2345,Type:9, stype: 'Casual',  dNoofDays: 3, sFromdate: '01 Aug 2013', sTodate: '04 Aug 2013', sFromopt: 'Full Day', sToopt: 'Full Day', Reason: 'test',......}

Comment: What are the dynamic values ? PNAME - > name ?

Comment: Dynamic values are: CODE, Name, iLeaveId, stype, dates, reason

Comment: did you try adding regular expression for each?

Comment: Thanks for guiding. Able to retrieve data using Reg Exp (for mngr1 10 EmpCodes) and can place these variables in the request. I am not sure if I am doing right thing as each manager will have different number of requests. The recorded script with mngr1 has 10 leave requests (http reqts) and second manager might have lesser number of leave requests (ex: 5). But the script has 10 requests recorded so for the second manager another 5 requests not applicable. And once again thanks a lot for guiding.

Comment: example: I get reg exp output values as Match count: 10 Match[1][0]=1234...similarly for other values. So Do I need to loop through these values with 1 leave request than having 10 requests recorded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use regular expression as post-processor to find each of the dynamic value.

For catching multiple values you should use  Match No. -1 in regular expression and add [ForEach Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) after it that will loop through all the values by entering the refernce name of the regular expression :

> It is especially suited for running with the regular expression post-processor. This can "create" the necessary input variables out of the result data of a previous request. By omitting the "_" separator, the ForEach Controller can be used to loop through the groups by using the input variable refName_g, and can also loop through all the groups in all the matches by using an input variable of the form refName_${C}_g, where C is a counter variable.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable suggestion, able to use it for one extracted value. However the request has to get 4 dynamic values at a time, with ForEach controller i could do for 1 dynamic value. For rest of the values getting 'not found' message (for these 3 values used reg exp variable)

Comment: Thanks for all suggestions. Able to achieve this by using: ${__V(EMP_CODE_${__counter(,)})} for the rest of the dynamic values under ForEach controller child request.